# PDF js worker bundled with a hashed name with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, pdf.js

I need to use PDF.js with Webpack, I followed the documentation that tells you to add an entry for pdf.worker.

Here is the entry and output of my webpack config:

```
entry: {
    index: './src/client/home/home.jsx',
    'pdf.worker': 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry'
},
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build/client'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: [name]-[chunkhash].js,
}
```

And still according to the documentation, in the javacript code, I need to specify the worker path like this:

```
pdfjsLib.PDFJS.workerSrc = '/pdf.worker.bundle.js';
```

The issue is that I use chunkhash for the generation of the file so it cannot find pdf.worker.bundle.js.

I see two solutions:

1. Remove the hash for the worker ONLY in webpack: [name]-bundle.js
   But how can I tell webpack to ONLY do this for the worker and not the other .js files?
2. Change the value of pdfjsLib.PDFJS.workerSrc after the code is generated, how can I do that?

Also, am I right to think that the first solution is not good since the user will always cache the same worker?

Comment: 2 years later, did you find any solution? I dont understand why i have to set the worker-src-url when it is already bundled and loaded by Webpack. Also Webpack will create a hashed name as you mentioned.